# Outlook requirement set version printed does not match the method that could be used

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I deployed an Outlook Web Addin with a customer:

Outlook desktop version : 2016

Exchange Server : 2013, 15.0.1497.7

3 methods from Office.js library broke the code execution : `Office.context.MailboxEnums.RestVersion` , `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync` and `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync`

I used `Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported` method to print supported version. Outlook desktop says it supports up to 1.4 requirement set. Outlook on the web says up to 1.3. The Microsoft doc says a 2013 Exchange Server limits us to 1.1 - which would explain the noticed behavior with that all three methods not supported under 1.3. The addin does not appear at all on OWA with IE 11 (!).

1. How can it be explained ? How can we prevent bugs from hapening if the client returns a requirement set supported which is far beyond what it actually is ? How should we manage these cases ?
2. What is the recommended way to open a web page from an addin in 1.1 requirement set : is there anything else possible rather than a pop up (window.open) which can be blocked ?

Comment: We have documentation on requirement sets here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets. It is possible to connect a newer version of Outlook Desktop to an older version of Exchange Server. This means that the client and server will support different requirement sets. So it appears that everything is working fine for you in Outlook Desktop, however, not quite the same in Outlook on the web?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT indeed, but that doesn't explain how a client can say it supports 1.3 set, while all 1.3 methods throw an error in this exact context.

Comment: If your target Exchange server and Outlook client support different requirement sets, then you're restricted to the lower requirement set range. For example, if an add-in is running in Outlook 2016 on Mac (highest requirement set: 1.6) against Exchange 2013 (highest requirement set: 1.1), your add-in is limited to requirement set 1.1. The recommendation is to use this minimum requirement set to avoid bugs.